# Find line with specific string in a file with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the category and the number of pages from a text file with python.

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
search = input("Which book are you looking for: ")
file = open("books.txt","r")

line_num = 0

reading = file.readlines()


# for line in file:
#  if search in file:
# NOT SURE HOW TO WRITE TO GET THE LINE NUMBER OF WHAT THE USER IS LOOKING FOR


book_category = line_num + 1
book_pages = line_num + 2

print(reading[book_category] , " " , reading[book_pages])

file.close()
```

And here is the file (books.txt)

```
Book one
Horror
300
Book two
Fantasy
150
Book three
Mystery
400
Book four
Romance
100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('books.txt') as fin :
    lines = fin.readlines()

line_num = -1
for k,line in enumerate(lines) :
    if line.find( search ) != -1 :
        line_num = k
```

The code above will search for the user input in the book titles, for example, if user inputs "Gob", all following books will match: "The Goblin", "The Life of Richard Gobbler" etc.

If you need an exact match, use:

```
if line.lower().strip() == search.lower().strip() :
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this problem is break the string / book into two parts everything before your target and after. Then split all of the stuff before your target by new line and count how many lines there are.

```
def line_no(inp, target):
    inp = inp.split(target)
    #inp[0] = everything before your target
    line_no = len(inp[0].split('\n'))  #split everything before your target by line and get a count
    #-1 for zero index
    return line_no

statement = '''Hello
World
I
Am
A
Statement'''

line_no(statement, 'Am')
```